# About the definition of Sylow p-groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, p-groups

Here is the definition of Sylow p-group (source: wikipedia)

> For a prime number p, a Sylow p-subgroup (sometimes p-Sylow subgroup) of a group G is a maximal p-subgroup of G, i.e. a subgroup of G that is a p-group (so that the order of every group element is a power of p) that is not a proper subgroup of any other p-subgroup of G. The set of all Sylow p-subgroups for a given prime p is sometimes written Sylp(G).

Does that mean it is possible that if I have $2$ sylow p-groups $P_1,P_2$ with $P_1 \neq P_2$ then

$|P_1| \neq |P_2|$ (if neither $P_1 \leq P_2,$ nor $P_2 \leq P_1)$ or am I misunderstanding the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **definition** would a priori  allow to have $|P_1|\ne|P_2|$. However, the Sylow **theorems** tell us that the Sylow p-subgroups are conjugates of each other and hence of same order (in fact, isomorphic).

Comment: That's the problem. In the proof of that Sylow theorem in my book, they used $|P_1| = |P_2|$. So that's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: @Math_QED Presumably, your book defines a Sylow $p$-subgroup as a subgroup of order $p^a$ (where $|G| = p^a n$ with $p \nmid n$). So it follows immediately that all Sylow $p$-subgroups are maximal (among $p$-subgroups). And presumably, your books goes on to prove the theorem that any $p$-subgroup of $G$ is contained inside a Sylow $p$-subgroup. From this, it follows that all maximal $p$-subgroups are Sylow $p$-subgroups. So the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: Sylow's theorems only apply to finite groups. For infinite groups it is possible to have $|P_1| \ne |P_2|$. If $P$ and $Q$ are any two $p$-groups, finite or infinite, then $P$ and $Q$ are both Sylow $p$-subgroups of the free product $P*Q$.

Answer (score 0):

Some authors *define* Sylow $p$-subgroups having order $p^k$ with $k$ maximal, see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sylowp-Subgroup.html):

Definition: If $p^k$ is the highest power of a prime $p$ dividing the order of a finite group $G$, then a subgroup of G of order $p^k$ is called a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

With this definition, $|P_1|=|P_2|$. There is also another definition
as a maximal $p$-subgroup of $G$, and then we would use a Sylow Theorem to show that
$P_1=gP_2g^{-1}$ for some $g$, so that $|P_1|=|P_2|$.

Comment: Yes, but that is not the definition being used in the question! The advantage of the wikipedia definition is that it makes sense for infinite groups, although for infinite groups they may not exist at all, or there may be two such groups that are not conjugate.

Answer (score 0):

If group $G$ is finite then $|P_1|=|P_2|$. For finite groups, wikipedia definition is equivalent to Dietrich Burde definition.

---

**Definition:** A subgroup $P$ of a group $G$ is said to be a Sylow $p$-subgroup ($p$ prime) if $P$ is a maximal $p$-subgroup of $G$ (that is, $P\lt H\lt G$ with $H$ a $p$-group implies $P= H$).

> **Lemma:** Let $G$ be a group of order $p^nm$ with $p$ prime, $n\gt 1$ and $(m,p) = 1$. Let $H$ be a $p$-subgroup of $G$. Then $H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ if and only if $|H| = p^n$.

**Proof:** $(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Since $H$ is a $p$-subgroup of finite group $G$, we have $|H|=p^i$ for some $i\geq 0$. If $i\gt n$. By Lagrange theorem, $|H|=p^i\mid p^nm=|G|$. Which implies $p^{i-n}|m$ and $(m,p)=p$. Which contradicts our hypothesis of $(m,p)=1$. If $i\lt n$. By proof of [first Sylow theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4779609/861687), $\exists K\lt G$ such that $H\subset K$ and $|K|=p^{i+1}$. Which contradicts the fact that $H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Thus $i=n$. Hence $|H|=p^n$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose $|H|=p^n$. Then $\nexists K\lt G$ such that $H\subset K$ and $K$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$. Thus $H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.